# Kafka: java.nio.channels.ClosedSelectorException

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have two kafka clusters. One is two broker node kafka cluster with replication factor 2 and second one is single broker kafka cluster. 
Sometimes observed below exception in Kafka controller.log. What would be the possible reason? Please help me

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedSelectorException

at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:83)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:489)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:298)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:349)
at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.recursivePoll$1(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:135)
at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.pollContinuously$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:142)
at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.blockingSendAndReceive$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:108)
at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.liftedTree1$1(ControllerChannelManager.scala:192)
at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:184)
at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
```

Answer (score 0):

I observed that problem when there is a connection problem. Main reason could be the zookeeper connection. Did you try to enable debug in kafka broker and read the logs? Because, you need to see detailed logs from server.

Comment: This is just a comment. Never write comments in answer section.